# Is it possible to use matplotlib's interactive plotting features within Django?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I know Matplotlib can be used in Django, based on the documentation. However, I'd like to be able to create interactive graphs within a webpage (i.e clickable points). In order to display a graph created in a Python script, Django spits out a png image. I haven't tested it out myself, but the fact that Django only spits out a png is worrisome. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Django.html

http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Matplotlib_Interactive_Plotting.html

Comment: Have you looked at dedicated libraries for this? E.g. MPLD3 or Bokeh.

Comment: I have not. I will definitely check those two out. Thanks!

Comment: Any update on this topic?

Comment: @aturegano I found that using MPLD3 works extremely well. There's a lot of documentation. There are many plugins available that are really clean.